# Custom theme settings not saving

Tags: 9, configuration

I am in Drupal 9.3 and I am working to add 5 new fields to the theme settings. I am following all the instructions I can find. I have tried clearing caches a few times. I can see the fields. But everytime I save the values dissappear.

Here is the code:

```
function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['price_spider'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('Price Spider'),
    '#open' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t("Your Price Spider settings."),
  ];

  $form['price_spider']['hide'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Hide Price Spider?'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('price_spider_hide'),
  ];

  $form['price_spider']['generic_key'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Generic Key'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('price_spider_generic_key'),
  ];

  $form['price_spider']['product_key'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Product Key'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('price_spider_product_key'),
  ];

  $form['price_spider']['country'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Country Code'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('price_spider_country'),
  ];

  $form['price_spider']['language'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Language Code'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('price_spider_language'),
  ];
}
```

---

**Update:**
To be sure, I found the original form in this file: docroot/core/modules/system/src/Form/ThemeSettingsForm.php

That form calls "theme_settings_convert_to_config" in file: docroot/core/includes/theme.inc

That function only specifically saves fields provided by the default form... except the line that reads "elseif (!in_array($key, ['theme', 'logo_upload']))" where it just up and saves the setting regardless.
So I dove into this using the devel module and the dpm() function (because my xdebug doesn't want to work right now).

Diving in, I see that when the form state gets to the part where the form loads all the values, what I entered is not there and each entry is empty. Maybe this is a validation thing.

I tried the idea of adding a submit function and when I do it never ends up running the submit function in the Core theme settings form. So other settings changes don't happen. Before there was no submit functions defined in the form array. By adding one it seems to break the process.

---

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to alter field value from submit handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295635/proper-way-to-alter-field-value-from-submit-handler)

Comment: Yeah, I guess the submit handler is missing?

Comment: I think probably not an issue here, but you may need to think about [#tree](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/form-api/tree-and-parents) and whether your field values are stored how you think they are.

Comment: It feels like we are on the right track here. But something is missing. I have updated the question with what I have found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The problem was that the name for the field and the name I was getting using "theme_get_setting" didn't match. So it never lines up. Fixed that and the problem is solved.

**Example:**

```
  $form['price_spider']['price_spider_generic_key'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Generic Key'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('price_spider_generic_key'),
  ];
```

Notice how both parts now say "price_spider_generic_key" (been playing around with the names). Matching those fixed it.